# Change original page and open a new page with one link - iOS 8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cross-browser

I have a link:

```
<a href="//facebook.com" target="_blank" id="scriptLink">Click Me!</a>
```

And I have this Javascript acting on it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#scriptLink').on('click',function(){
        window.location.href = '//google.com'; 
    });
});
```

I haven't tested every single iOS, but on the iPhone 6 when the link is clicked it will only execute the JavaScript Google link and not the Facebook link. Is there some kind of preventDefault going on here, or am I writing this wrong? I've done some research into these cross-browser JavaScript links, but it seems the solutions the the askers' questions were specific to their use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `href` value `href="#"`.

In the `click` function add the 2 lines:

```
window.open("/*place link 1 within quotes*/");
window.open("/*place link 2 within quotes*/");
```

So it would look like:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="scriptLink">Click Me!</a>
```

And for example if the 2 links would be http://facebook.com and http://google.com, the script would be:

```
$('#scriptLink').click(function(){
  window.open("http://facebook.com");
  window.open("http://google.com");
});
```

**Update based on question update:** If you want the page to open 1 new link and the current tab to go to another page put the new tab/window in a `window.open` and the page you want the current tab/window to go to in the `href`.
So if you want the current page to go to http://facebook.com and you want the new tab/window to go to http://google.com it would look like this:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank" id="scriptLink">Click Me!</a>
```

And the script would be:

```
$('#scriptLink').click(function(){
  window.open("http://google.com");
});
```

Comment: This answer is correct based off the original title. UpVoted

Comment: If you want to change the page to a new page and then open the second link separately, put one link in the `href` and use 1 `window.open` for the second.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how I'm going to make it out of this life alive.